# Mapping a servlet in web.xml eclipse? (Dynamic Project)

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, servlets

Basically I am trying to Map a servlet to my web.xml file in Eclipse, But then  when I call my servlet at browser I get the apache error 404 (File Not Found) Error.

```
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>watch</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>duck.reg.pack.watch</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>watch</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/watch</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Project Name `Duck`.

But then when I call it as `http://localhost:20012/Duck/watch` Apache error 404 is showen.

Much Regards

Comment: Are you sure your class is `duck.reg.pack.watch` and not starts with capital letter?

Comment: @Oleg ahh 100% sure

Comment: Maybe the context root is not the project name. Check the context root in Web Project Settings under project properties. Is it "Duck"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small list of possible things you can check:

1. Check the servlet is inside the package `duck.reg.pack.watch`
2. Make sure your form method is mapped onto the correct doGet or doPost request. A common mistake is incorrect mapping (doing a doPost request when your servlet only has a doGet)
3. Servlet names by convention are capitalized.
4. Create a doGet method (if you don't already have one) and check if the following mapping works:

> ```
> localhost:20012/Duck/watch
>
> localhost:20012/watch
> ```

5. Restart and clean/rebuild your server. Depending on your configuration, sometimes changes made in web.xml do not reflect until you restart the server.